# How to change tab label in Angular Material?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7, angular8

I have tab group:

```
  <mat-tab-group [selectedIndex]="tabService.activeTabIndex()" (selectedTabChange)="tabChanged($event)">
    <mat-tab label="{{ tabTitle }}"></mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="{{ tabTitle }}"></mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>>
```

How to change label (title) for tab with index 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this is done simply by setting which title you wish to use.

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab label="First"> Content 1 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Second"> Content 2 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Third"> Content 3 </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

if you need to set it as a variable, you can insert different variables to each `label`.

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab [label]=title1> Content 1 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab [label]=title2> Content 2 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab [label]=title3> Content 3 </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

in TS:

```
  title1 = 'Title 1';
  title2 = 'Title 2';
  title3 = 'Title 3';
```

StackBlitz example : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x4yzr6?file=app/tab-group-basic-example.ts
source: https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview

Comment: I know. but I need change it dynamically,

Comment: I know only index tab which I want chnage

Comment: @user3573738 I have edited the question. mark as resolved if I helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can access MatTabGroup's internal list of tabs to achieve what you want.

In your TS component, add the following lines:

```
@ViewChild('tabGroup') private tabGroup: MatTabGroup;
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.tabGroup._tabs.first.textLabel = 'New Label'; 
}
```

Change your HTML to:

```html
<mat-tab-group #tabGroup>
    ...
</mat-tab-group>
```